# Golang package installation fails

Tags: go, golint

I'm having a problem with package installation it worked before but suddenly I'm getting this message:

```
package github.com/golang/lint/golint
    imports github.com/golang/lint
    imports go/types: unrecognized import path "go/types"
package github.com/golang/lint/golint
    imports github.com/golang/lint
    imports golang.org/x/tools/go/gcimporter15
    imports golang.org/x/tools/go/gcimporter15
    imports golang.org/x/tools/go/gcimporter15: no buildable Go source files in /go/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/gcimporter15
```

Heres my GO env output:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/student/Documents/GO_WORKSPACE"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Comment: Do you already have an `golang.org/x/tools/go/gcimporter` empty directory?

Comment: No I dont have. I've deleted tools directory and tryed to go get it again but it result in same output